# How to display model name (basically LabelFor's inner text)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'd like to have the functionality of printing out a model's member name/display name. This is akin to using `HtmlHelper<TModel>.LabelFor` but having the text *not* wrapped in a `label`. Is there an extension method already built into MVC for this exact purpose? I couldn't find one so I looked at what `LabelFor` does with Reflector and made a `LabelTextFor` method:

```
public static string LabelTextFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> source, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    var memberName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText((LambdaExpression)expression);

    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>());

    return metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? memberName.Split('.').Last();
}
```

I'm thinking I should maybe change the name as well of this method. Thoughts are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to use the method that I've created.

Answer (score 0):

MVC Shipped HTML Extension is not designed for customizing looks, rather, it is designed for more 'semantic' description for your purpose.

What you want to do, is actually simpler that don't require an extra extension, but via custom templates. Please look at [Brad Wilson's great article series](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html) for how to do so.

Comment: Sure, I understand the semantics for the built in extensions. I'm doing something very explicit with a model's name that doesn't require a template or anything down that route. Regardless, after seeing that even Brad uses the `ModelMetadata` to extract the information, I think I'm safe with my current extension method. Perhaps renaming it will better suit my needs though. Thanks.